# Prompt use to save to iCloud WITHOUT using UIActivityViewController

Tags: save, icloud, uiactivityviewcontroller

If I use the following code

```
NSArray * activityItems = @[tempFileURL];

UIActivityViewController * activityViewController =
    [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems: activityItems
                                      applicationActivities: nil];


[self.parentViewController presentViewController: activityViewController
                                        animated: YES
                                      completion: nil];
```

Then choose 'Save to Files', I am presented with the following dialog:

[image: Save to files]

I would like to present this dialog without needing to first go though `UIActivityViewController` (and the 'save to files' option) first. I haven't been able to find an alternative way to do this. Any suggestions?

Specifically, my question boils down to this:
How can I have a user specify where a file should be saved without going though `UIActivityViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. And I found a solution.

You can use `UIDocumentPickerViewController` for that purpose.

```
// in Your ViewController
let viewController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(urls: [tempFileURL], in: .exportToService)
present(viewController, animated: true)
```

You can get a screen like the following one.
[image]

You can see Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/FileProvider.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH18-SW1).